# Forerunner DB not persisting in Node (electron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, forerunnerdb

I'm trying to scrape my music folder for mp3 file paths, and save it to my DB. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
const ForerunnerDB = require("forerunnerdb");
const fdb = new ForerunnerDB();
const db = fdb.db("DB");
db.persist.dataDir('/data');
let songCollection = db.collection("songs");

function generateLibrary(path) {
  if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
    console.log("Directory '", path ,"' does not exist.");
    return;
  }

  fs.readdir(path, function(err, results) {
    for (let item of results) {
      let curFilePath = pathTools.join(path, item);
      fs.lstat(curFilePath, function(err, stats) {
        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
          saveDB(generateLibrary(curFilePath)); // Save between directories
        } else if (pathTools.extname(curFilePath) === ".mp3") {
          console.log("Adding: ", curFilePath);
          songCollection.insert({path: curFilePath});
        }
      });
    }
  })
}

function saveDB(callback) {
  console.log("Saving");
  songCollection.save(function (err) {
    console.log("Ping")
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Saved song collection.");
      if (callback) { callback(); }
    } else {
      console.log("Saving failed, this shouldn't happen.");
      if (callback) { callback(); }
    }
  });
}

generateLibrary("D:/Music");
```

As you can see, I'm using a callback to save before recursively searching folders. This seems like a good increment. However, nothing will save! I hit the `Saving` log point in `saveDB()`, but it never hits the `Ping`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This question was answered on the ForerunnerDB issue tracker in GitHub for anyone who is interested in seeing the conversation. https://github.com/Irrelon/ForerunnerDB/issues/78

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered on the ForerunnerDB issue tracker in GitHub for anyone who is interested in seeing the conversation. Copying and pasting the (lengthy) conversation here would probably not be productive.

https://github.com/Irrelon/ForerunnerDB/issues/78